How to show that $\Bbb{P}^n$ is birational to $\Bbb{A}^n$?
I am reading a lecture note and am trying to prove that $\Bbb{P}^n$ is birational to $\Bbb{A}^n$.
My definitions

Definition 4.5. A rational map $\langle U, \varphi \rangle : X \dashrightarrow Y$ of varieties is called dominant if $\varphi(U)$ is dense in $Y$. 
Definition 4.7. A dominant rational map $\varphi : X \dashrightarrow Y$ is called a birational map if there exists a dominant rational map $\varphi^{-1} : Y \dashrightarrow X$ with $\varphi \circ \varphi^{-1} = \text{id}_Y$, $\varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi = \text{id}_X$.
$X$ and $Y$ are called birationally equivalent (or just birational) if there exists a birational map $\varphi : X \dashrightarrow Y$.

With these definitions, I came up with the following maps; $\Bbb A^n \to \Bbb P^n$ by $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto [1:x_1:\cdots:x_n]$ and $\Bbb P^n \dashrightarrow \Bbb A^n$ by $[x_0:\cdots:x_n]\mapsto (x_1/x_0,\cdots,x_n/x_0)$. It's easy to see that $\Bbb A^n\to\Bbb P^n\dashrightarrow \Bbb A^n$ is the identity, we have $\Bbb P^n\dashrightarrow \Bbb A^n\to\Bbb P^n$ is also the identity. This shows these two maps are rational inverses, and each is a birational map. Thus, $\mathbb{P}^n$ is birational to $\mathbb{A}^n$.
But I came across the following ping-pong on MSE.
Proposed proof

Let $\Bbb{P}^n$ be the projective $n$-space and $\Bbb{A}^n$ the affine $n$-space. It is said that $\Bbb{P}^n$ is birational to $\Bbb{A}^n$ but they are not isomorphic. In the case of $\Bbb{P}^1$ and $\Bbb{A}^1$. I think that we can define rational maps $\varphi: \Bbb{P}^1 \to \Bbb{A}^1$ by $\varphi(x_0 : x_1) = x_1/x_0$ if $x_0 \neq 0$ $\varphi(x_0:x_1)= 0$ if $x_0=0$. Define $\psi: \Bbb{A}^1 \to \Bbb{P}^1$ by $\psi(x) = (1:x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $\psi(x)=(0:1)$ if $x = 0$. Then $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are inverse of each other. Therefore $\Bbb{P}^1$ and $\Bbb{A}^1$ are birational.

Counter argument

There is something wrong with your attempt in trying to show $\Bbb{P}^1$ is birational to $\Bbb{A}^1$. Remember a birational map is only defined on an open subset of your space and not necessarily on all of $\Bbb{P}^1$. There are issues with the map $\Bbb{P}^1 \to \Bbb{A}^1$ you defined above. First it is not injective because $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are both mapped to the same point (so how can there be an " inverse"?).

cite: How to show that $\Bbb{P}^n$ is birational to $\Bbb{A}^n$ but they are not isomorphic?
My question
I didn't find that the answerer alternatively propose another map so I am not sure how to go about this proof. Can anyone tell me right maps or right direction?
Other Relevant previous post on MSE

Is $\mathbb{C}P^n$ birational to $\mathbb{C}^n$?


Definition 4.7 is slightly wrong. Notice that a rational map $\phi:X \dashrightarrow Y$ is not defined as $X$ as a whole, but on an open subset $U$ (and if one wants to be precise, a rational map is an equivalence class of maps from open subsets which coincide on the intersections). So a birational map is a rational map $\phi:X \dashrightarrow Y$ such that there is a rational map $\psi:Y \dashrightarrow X$ such that $\phi \circ \psi$ is the identity on an open subset of Y and $\psi \circ \phi$ is the identity on an open subset of X ! In other words, $\phi$ is birational if it induces an isomorphism between open subsets of $X$ and $Y$.
Thus, in your example, your map $\Bbb A^1 \rightarrow \Bbb P^1 \dashrightarrow \Bbb A^1$ is indeed the identity on $\Bbb A^1$ (an open subset of itself), but $\Bbb P^1 \dashrightarrow \Bbb A^1 \rightarrow \Bbb P^1$ is the identity on an open subset of $\Bbb P^1$. BUT as indicated by the definition above, this is enough to conclude that you have defined a birational map.
The counter-argument of the post you quote is simply an observation that the author was trying to define a map on the whole of $\Bbb P^1$. The answer shows how the map is not a regular map (i.e. it is a map of sets, sure, but not a morphism). However, when dealing with rational maps, there is no harm in defining maps on open subsets as you did, rather than trying to extend them to the whole space.
